# Express JS and Mongo DB connection issues

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the simple code of connecting the express js to mongodb, and i also install the both packages, so why i'm facing this error?

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log("Server is running at port number 3000");
})

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase",{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
})
.then(()=>{console.log("Connection is Succeed")})
.catch((e) => { console.error("Received an Error", e); });
```

Error I'm facing, they are not connecting.

```
Server is running at port number 3000
(node:25888) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useNewUrlParser is a deprecated option: useNewUrlParser has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version       
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:25888) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useUnifiedTopology is a deprecated option: useUnifiedTopology has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version 
Received an Error MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Desktop\web dev\Backend Development\Express and MongoDB connections\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:809:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Desktop\web dev\Backend Development\Express and MongoDB connections\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:784:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Comment: Do you think maybe there might be some information in the `e` error variable? Try `console.error("Received an Error", e)`. Also, if you want to run the app on port `3000`, don't pass in `300`

Comment: @Phil after doing the your changes i'm facing the same error

Comment: I didn't say it would fix anything. What does your logging say now though? Please [edit] your question to include any code changes and any new error messages

Comment: You still aren't logging the `e` value. Why not? It will literally tell you what's wrong

Comment: To make it perfectly clear, change your last line to `.catch((e) => { console.error("Received an Error", e); });` and [edit] your question to include the updated error report

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. just replace the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.
So your code changes from this:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase",{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
})
```

to:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDatabase",{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase' try below code

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log("Server is running at port number 3000");
})


mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDatabase",{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
})
.then(()=>{console.log("Connection is Succeed")})
.catch((e)=>{console.log("Received an Error")});
```